# Keeping records revisions

Tags: mysql, database, mediawiki

I have a list of articles and its revisions. In this scenario, only two rules are important:

(i) When someone requests a specific revision of an article, it should be delivered.

(ii) When someone requests an article just informing the article identifier, the latest revision of the article should be delivered.

To have a list of articles with its latest revisions we use the following view:

```
CREATE  OR REPLACE VIEW `only_articles` AS
  SELECT *
    FROM article AS a
    WHERE a.revision = (
        SELECT MAX(ma.revision) AS max_revision
        FROM article AS ma
        WHERE ma.id = a.id
    );
```

Is there any way to optimize this query? Is there any way to avoid the sub-query? Is there any better way to store these revisions?

This is the table structure (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
  `ai_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `revision` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ai_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_VERSION` (`id`,`revision`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Some data:

```
ai_id   id      revision  title
1       1       1         'Text one'
2       1       2         'Text two'
3       1       3         'Text three'
4       2       1         'Another Article'
5       2       2         '2nd revision of another article'
```

Expected output:

```
ai_id   id      revision  title
3       1       3         'Text three'
5       2       2         '2nd revision of another article'
```

I don't believe that the project needs a Temporal Database only to address this issue. This is the only table that needs versioning also the stored content is too small (about 2KB per record).

It seems that this situation has been faced by many good CMS and Wikis (such as MediaWiki or Wordpress). Any tips on how they solved and the advantages and disadvantages of the methods used in these projects?

Comment: use a separate article_history table to store revisions. See Hibernate Envers

Answer (score 0):

Mediawiki has separate tables for [page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Page_table) and [revision](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Revision_table), and page table stores an `rev_id` of latest revision in `page_latest` field.